# Virtuoso with Owl API only

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, virtuoso

There seem to be a lot of resources on using Virtuoso with Jena thanks to the availability of the [virt-jena](https://github.com/srdc/virt-jena). I wonder if there is an existing binding of virtuoso with owl api.

I know that a jena model can be used to create OwlOntology, but that makes things redundant (having to use both jena and owl api codes in my application). So, my question is can virtuoso be accessed using owl api only? Is there some driver to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Feature requests such as this are often best raised directly to the project, via either the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) or  the [github-based issues page] (https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Answer (score 0):

Not at present. We (owl api) are working on adding commons rdf support, but it's not possible at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Looking forward to your binding.